# Keep playing audio after setTimeout

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I'm doing an HTML5 web-app where the user unlocks some features clicking and holding a button for 1 sec. So far so good, but it comes along with an audio.

If the user clicks and relase the button before 1 sec, the audio stops and starts again if they click it again.

So, what I'm trying to achieve is to keep playing the audio if the users hold the button clicked after one sec.

This is what I've got so far: (READ IMPORTANT NOTE BELOW)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var audio = $("#sound")[0];
    
    $("#play").mousedown(function(e) {
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        $("#sound").prop("volume", 1);
        audio.play();
        clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
        this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            audio.play();
        }, 1000);
    }).
    mouseup(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
        $("#sound").get(0).pause();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="play">Press me</button>
<audio id='sound' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Cello_Live_Performance_John_Michel_Tchaikovsky_Violin_Concerto_3rd_MVT_applaused_cut.ogg'/>
```

This code must be mobile-friendly, on IOS if you click hold some `div` more than .5 sec, it highlights the content. So... bonus points if someone tells me how to unable the IOS highlight on Safari and get this done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is save the time when you click (mousedown) and when you release (mouseup) calculate the difference, so you only pause if the difference is smaller than 1 second... This will do the trick...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var audio = $("#sound")[0];
    var start = 0;

    $("#play").mousedown(function(e) {
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        $("#sound").prop("volume", 1);
        audio.play();
        clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
        start = Date.now();
        this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            audio.play();
        }, 1000);
    }).
    mouseup(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
        if ((Date.now()-start) < 1000)
            $("#sound").get(0).pause();
    });
});
```

If you click again, it stops the music and start again checking the 1 second limit. I hope it helps